# How to check forwarded Packets in UDPBasicApp in Omnet

Tags: udp, omnet++, inet

How can I modify UDPBasicApp to find duplicates in the messages recieved?
I made these changes to the class UDPBasicApp.cc to add an extra step to check recieved udp data packets like below, but I see no effect in .sca/.vec and does not even show bubbles.
Where could the error be?

```
void UDPBasicApp::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) 
{

 if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
     ASSERT(msg == selfMsg); 
     switch (selfMsg->getKind()) {
         case START:
             processStart(); 
             break;

         case SEND:
             processSend();
             break;

         case STOP:
             processStop();
             break; 

         default: 
             throw cRuntimeError("Invalid kind %d in self message", (int)selfMsg->getKind());
     } 
 }

 else if (msg->getKind() == UDP_I_DATA) { 
     // process incoming packet
     //-----------------------------------------------------Added step
                     //std::string currentMsg= "" + msg->getTreeId(); 
                    std::string currentPacket= PK(msg)->getName();
                      if( BF->CheckBloom(currentPacket) == 1) {
                        numReplayed++;
                        getParentModule()->bubble("Replayed!!");
                        EV<<"----------------------WSNode "<<getParentModule()->getIndex() <<": REPLAYED! Dropping Packet\n";
                           delete msg;
                           return;
                        }
                        else 
                           { 
                             BF->AddToBloom(currentPacket);
                             numLegit++;
                             getParentModule()->bubble("Legit.");
                             EV<<"----------------------WSNode "<<getParentModule()->getIndex() <<":OK. Pass.\n";
                        }
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     processPacket(PK(msg));
 }

 else if (msg->getKind() == UDP_I_ERROR) {
     EV_WARN << "Ignoring UDP error report\n";
     delete msg;
 }
 else { 
     throw cRuntimeError("Unrecognized message (%s)%s", msg->getClassName(), msg->getName());
 } 
 if (hasGUI()) {
     char buf[40];
     sprintf(buf, "rcvd: %d pks\nsent: %d pks", numReceived, numSent);
     getDisplayString().setTagArg("t", 0, buf);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you show declaration and definition of `BF` object?

Comment: you want to check whether a message has been received twice?

Comment: Yes, please notice "forwarded" not "received"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have enough context about the entities participating in your overall system, I will provide the following idea:

You can add a unique ID to each message of your application by adding the following line to your applications `*.msg`:

```
int messageID = simulation.getUniqueNumber();
```

Now on the receiver side you can have an `std::map<int, int> myMap` where you store the `<id,number-of-occurences>`

Each time you receive a message you add the message to the `std::map` and increment the `number-of-occurences`

```
if(this->myMap.count(myMessage->getUniqueID) == 0) /* check whether this ID exists in the map */
{
    this->myMap.insert(std::make_pair(myMessage->getUniqueID(), 1));    /* add this id to the map and set the counter to 1 */
}
else
{
    this->myMap.at(myMessage->getUniqueID())++; /* add this id to the map and increment the counter */

}
```

This will allow you to track whether the same message has been forwarded twice, simply by doing:

```
if(this->myMap.at(myMessage->getUniqueID()) != 1 ) /* the counter is not 1, message has been "seen" more than once */
```

The tricky thing for you is how do you define whether a message has been seen twice (or more).